# What is this sheet-like part in this circuit? Can I cut through it?

Tags: circuit-design, soldering

[image]

I have this remote-control circuit (front and back.)

What is this sheet thing where I put a red question mark (?) on?

The reason I ask is because I want to cut a hole in the circuit board where you see that black circle.

Is that even ok? What happens to the circuit if I cut through that sheet?
I want to make room for a new button that I want to fit in.

Also, once I cut this hole, will I be able to see and connect the "printed" wire?
I know (and tested) that all I have to do is connect/solder the button ends, connecting the two ends within the black circle (that's where the old button was that I yanked out,) but what happens to the printed circuit wires if I cut the hole?
Will I be able to connect/solder on the wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's copper, a single flat piece of copper, the technical term for a extensive area of copper plating like this is a "pour".  You can cut it with a knife saw it with a saw or drill it with a drill.

Its purpose is either to shield the enclosed circuit or to act as a counterpoise for the antnna. if you remove some of it it may change the operation of the circuit, but you can probably mitigate this by adding some copper foil to the sides of the switch and connecting it to the cut edge.

When you cut the hole the printed wire will break  so remember which bit connected to where and use wires to replicate those connections.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, @Jasen!
It's not as beautiful as I expected my soldering would go, but it's only my second soldering project in my life... and it works! So, I'm happy :)